# How do I merge KML files without overlaps or vertices in-between?

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth

I have 3 `.KML` files and want to merge them to create one large `.KML` but can't seem to remove the vertices in between.

[image: merge example]

When I merge them directly, they have overlaps and vertices in between them like in the above diagram. I need to get it to a clean path like in the diagram below it.

I can get rid of the overlaps with the `geoprocessing tools` (getting the intersection, getting the difference between that and the middle path, etc.) but I can't ever seem to get rid of the vertices.

Any tips on how I could approach this? I'm using QGIS and Google Earth Pro.

Comment: Have you tried the Dissolve operation under the geoprocessing tools?

Comment: I ended up merging the `.KML` files by converting them to `.csv` files and manually pasting/removing coordinates. I'll try out the dissolve operation now though, thanks!